# Why does a const reference behave differently when assigned an l-value and r-value?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Given the code sample below;

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 4;
    const int &b = a;
    const int &c = a * 2;
    a = 10;
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the output is

```
10
8
```

Why is C++ designed to behave differently when assigning l-value and r-value to const references?

Comment: The object c is bound to is different to the object b is bound to.

Comment: You want `c` to be re-evaluated automagically from the expression `a*2` everytime you change `a`? That is **too ambitious**!!

Comment: Yeah, the real question is what you thought would happen instead, and why... And when you think about what would be required to make any reference to a temporary involving any lvalue(s) always reflect any change to said lvalue(s), things quickly become ludicrously unmanageable, grammatically hopelessly ambiguous, and really quite scary to imagine. Just look at it literally: the RHS is an rvalue temporary, which is lifetime-extended by the `const` reference. _Effectively_, this is just like declaring a `const` lvalue named `c`, not a reference, although the mechanism is of course the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression:

```
const int &c = a * 2;
```

Does NOT bind the resulting reference `c` to `a`. Instead it binds it to the rvalue that is the result of the expression `a * 2`, which is a temporary object that no longer has anything to do with `a` - thus changing `a` does not affect it.

This is as opposed to `b`, which is a reference to the object `a`.

Answer (score 5):

```
const int &b = a;
const int &c = a * 2;
```

The `b` here is a reference (an alias) for `a`; as `a` changes value, `b` will reflect that.

`c` binds to the temporary object as calculated by the expression `a * 2`, as `a` changes value after the computation, the calculation is not recomputed, the value of `c` remains as it was originally computed.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers already explain why you get the output that you get. However, lets assume you want

```
const int &c = a * 2;
a = 10;
cout << c << endl;
```

to print `20`. This is possible, but not by using a const ref directly, e.g. like this:

```
struct myref {
    const int& x;
    myref(int& x) : x(x) {}
    operator int() { return x*2;}
};

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    myref c(a);
    a = 10;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

However, I would strongly suggest you not to use this code and I just wanted to demonstrate that it is possible (I took the "this is too ambitious" in a comment as a challenge).

I guess with lambdas this can be done in a much more elegant way, unfortunately I am not so familar with them.

Comment: It's easy - `auto myNonRef = [&x]{ return x * 2; }; /* ... */ std::cout << myNonRef() << std::endl;` - although obviously you are then confined to function-call syntax as a lambda cannot have a conversion operator like your custom class.

Comment: @underscore_d but one could write a struct like mine that takes a lambda as parameter, then at least my approach would be flexible. However I have strong doubts whether using an `operator int` is such a good idea

Comment: True, a template struct receiving and storing the lambda. But yeah, I'm not sure this has much practical usefulness, at least not in common cases. And it's totally orthogonal to the concept of references.

Comment: @underscore_d well, one could write a assignment operator that assigns 1/2 of the value to the referenced int (or more generally the value after applying the inverse function). Imho quite interesting, but I would be careful with using something like this

Comment: For sure, I think it could be extremely useful in relevant cases - like maybe mathematical models or others, and that's a good example - but just that such cases are relatively rare. Just trying to avoid people thinking this is a generally applicable technique!